# How to make indentation follow beginning of text in list

Tags: indentation, electric-indent

I want `electric-indent` or more generally, hitting `ENT`, to indent the
new line to the beginning of text. I'd like this to work with
`auto-fill` as well.

Before:

```
1. This is a long list item that I'll wrap at 50
chars. This is what happens.
2. Next item.
```

After:

```
1. This is a long list item that I'll wrap at 50
   chars. This is what I want.
2. Next item.
```

I'd even accept a solution that let's me fix this after the fact,
meaning I'm okay with highlighting the region and entering a command
that indents it the way I want. Something built-in preferred.

Comment: What is the buffer's major mode?

Comment: Major mode: `text-mode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `markdown-mode`, `auto-fill` will indent as desired.

It also has convenient functions for adding a new list item (`markdown-insert-list-item`) and re-numbering a list (`markdown-cleanup-list-numbers`), while staying very close to `text-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is either `outline-mode` or `org-mode`, both of which will give you this behavior.

Comment: Interesting, I never tried `outline-mode`. Will give it a shot!

Comment: Does not work as expected. Same behavior as `text-mode`.